# I need help finding an infinite loop or something because the code that I have doesn't run

Tags: python, numpy, interpolation, numeric

Im trying to calculate the hill coefficient of two logistic functions, f(x) and g(x), their composition, c(x), and input it in a datatable. Additionally, I am inputting the functions themselves, their composition and the product of hill coefficients of f(x) and g(x). In order to calculate the hill coefficients I am using a numeric bisection method as well.

Here's my code:

```
# Imports
import numpy as np
from numpy import log as ln
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from random import randint
import sympy as sym
import pandas as pd
import math


# initializing data
data = {'row': [],
        'f(x)': [],
        'g(x)': [],
        'f(g(x))': [],
        'H_f': [],
        'H_g': [],
        'H_fg': [],
        'Product of H_f and H_g': [],
        'Does this prove hypothesis?': []
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#True Randomization
def logrand(b):
    ra = randint(1,b)
    ra = float(ra/100)
    ra = 10**ra
    ra = round(ra)
    ra = int(ra)
    return ra

# Two Hill functions
num1 = 10
number = 1
for _ in range(num1):
        # Params
        u = 10
        c1 = logrand(300)
        r1 = randint(1,u)
        k1 = logrand(300)

        c2 = logrand(300)
        r2 = randint(1,u)
        k2 = logrand(300)

        # function layout
        funcf = '{}/({}+e^(-{}x))'.format(c1, k1, r1)
        funcg = '{}/({}+e^(-{}x))'.format(c2, k2, r2)
        funcc = '{}/({}+e^(-{}({}/({}+e^(-{}x)))))'.format(c1, k1, r1, c2, k2, r2)

        # figure layout
        plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [7.50, 3.50]
        plt.rcParams["figure.autolayout"] = True


        # Hill Function for f(x) and g(x) and f(g(x))
        def f(x):
                return c1 / (k1 + np.exp((-1*r1) * x))


        def g(x):
            return c2 / (k2 + np.exp((-1*r2) * x))


        def comp(x):
                return c1 / (k1 + np.exp((-1*r1) * (c2 / (k2 + np.exp((-1*r2) * x)))))



        # EC finder
        def BisectionEC10(fa, a, b):
                c = 1
                x = np.linspace(a, b, 1000)
                ystar = 0.10 * (fa(x).max() - fa(x).min())
                while abs(fa(c) - ystar) > 0.000000001:
                        c = (a + b) / 2
                        if fa(c) - ystar < 0:
                                a = c
                        elif fa(c) - ystar > 0:
                                b = c
                # print('The EC10 of the function is: ',"{0:.15f}".format(c))
                # print('Output of the function when evaluated at the EC10: ',fa(c))
                return c



        def BisectionEC90(fa, a, b):
                c = 1
                x = np.linspace(a, b, 1000)
                ystar = 0.90 * (fa(x).max() - fa(x).min())
                while abs(fa(c) - ystar) > 0.000000001:
                        c = (a + b) / 2
                        if fa(c) - ystar < 0:
                                a = c
                        elif fa(c) - ystar > 0:
                                b = c
                # print('The EC90 of the function is: ',"{0:.15f}".format(c))
                # print('Output of the function when evaluated at the EC90: ',fa(c))
                return c



        # EC90 and EC10 for f(x), g(x) and f(g(x))
        up = 20
        lo = 0
        # x = np.linspace[lo,up,1000]
        x = 1
        # x = sym.symbols('x')

        EC90_1 = BisectionEC90(f, lo, up)
        EC10_1 = BisectionEC10(f, lo, up)

        EC90_2 = BisectionEC90(g, lo, up)
        EC10_2 = BisectionEC10(g, lo, up)

        EC90_3 = BisectionEC90(comp, lo, up)
        EC10_3 = BisectionEC10(comp, lo, up)

        # Hill Coefficient for f(x) and g(x)
        H_1 = ln(81) / (ln(EC90_1 / EC10_1))
        H_1 = round(H_1,4)
        H_2 = ln(81) / (ln(EC90_2 / EC10_2))
        H_2 = round(H_2,4)
        H_3 = ln(81) / (ln(EC90_3 / EC10_3))
        H_3 = round(H_3,4)


        prod = float(H_1.real) * float(H_2.real)
        if prod >= float(H_3.real):
                answer = 'yes'
        else:
                answer = 'no'
        prod = round(prod,4)

        # adding all data to dataframe 2
        data2 = {'row': [number],
                 'f(x)': [funcf],
                 'g(x)': [funcg],
                 'f(g(x))': [funcc],
                 'H_f': [H_1],
                 'H_g': [H_2],
                 'H_fg': [H_3],
                 'Product of H_f and H_g': [prod],
                 'Does this prove hypothesis?': [answer]
                 }
        number = number + 1
        df = df.append(data2, ignore_index=True)

#final dataframe
print(df)
df.to_csv(r'/Users/*****/Desktop/Research/twoarctanfuncs.csv', index = False)
```

Now the problem that im stuck in is that the code just doesn't run, or that it has an infinite loop and I can't figure out where the problem is happening.

This is the error message when I force stop it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/*****/Documents/Python/NumericBisectionMethod/venv/twologisticfuncs.py", line 112, in <module>
    EC90_1 = BisectionEC90(f, lo, up)
  File "/Users/*****/Documents/Python/NumericBisectionMethod/venv/twologisticfuncs.py", line 95, in BisectionEC90
    if fa(c) - ystar < 0:
  File "/Users/*****/Documents/Python/NumericBisectionMethod/venv/twologisticfuncs.py", line 60, in f
    return c1 / (k1 + np.exp((-1*r1) * x))
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Use a debugger or simple print statements to try to pin point where things go wrong.

Comment: Or *"comment out"* large chunks of code till it runs so you find which chunk is blocking progress. Do this by surrounding the code with triple double quotes, i.e. `"""code to ignore"""`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your binary search (bisection) isn't starting with a large enough span.

1. I quickly tried your code, and then added the statement `print (a, b, c)` inside the `while` loop of `BisectionEC90`. The output quickly converged to `0 0.0 0.0` and stayed there.
2. I replaced that print statement with `print (abs(fa(c)), ystar)` and the output converged to `0.025157232704402517 0.00014330069262001276`.

So it makes sense that the code never exits the loop `while abs(fa(c) - ystar) > 0.000000001:`

---

**EDIT**: it would be a good idea to add some error checking into the `while` loop of your `Bisection` functions to prevent this type of infinite loop. Maybe something like this:

```py
if b - a < 0.000000001:
   raise Exception("Failed to find solution; a={}, b={}".format(a,b))
```

Comment: Hmm, im still kinda confused on what you guys mean. I am trying to use print statements in the while loops but I don't understand how that would help me fix it.

Comment: The `print (a,b,c)` statement shows you exactly what the problem is. Your function `BisectionEC90` starts with lower and upper limits of 0 and 20. As your program iterates, these limits change to [0, 10], then [0, 5], then [0, 2.5] ... up until it reaches [0, 0]. In other words, *your starting range of 0 to 20 isn't a wide enough range*. That's what the `print (a,b,c)` statement tells us.

Comment: Ive used the print function however im actually only getting zeros.

Comment: As I said, the values go to [0, 0] pretty quickly. You'll want to look at the values of the print function on the first few iterations of your loop. The simplest way to do this is to run your program and give it a keyboard interrupt immediately after it starts, then you can scroll up and look at the first few outputs. Or, if you are on a Linux system, you can use the Unix `head` command: `python myprog.py | head -20` to see the first 20 outputs.

Comment: I've changed the range from 0 to 20000 and it still instantly goes to 0. How can I fix this?

Comment: Since the answer is going to 0, you need to decrease the lower end of your range rather than increasing the upper range. Instead of changing [0,20] to [0, 20000], you need to change [0,20] to something like [-20,20]. I tried running `BisectionEC90` and `f(x)` by hand using Microsoft Excel and the correct answer was -1.95. Your answer will be different because your code uses random numbers. But it appears the answer must be less than zero.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a print statement or debugger, you will be able to detect the issue. You are stuck in a while loop, which means your condition is never satisfied. There could be multiple reasons, and to find out the exact issue, you would have to debug it. Although the most logical conclusion is that while `abs(fa(c) - ystar) > 0.000000001` is not being satisfied as mentioned by @Mr. Snrub

I would also recommend using the if conditions to break the loop in such cases.